# Cascading External Data in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, bcs

I have a list called "Jobs" that have two columns (Type External Data) called "Company" and "Project". When the user selects a Company, I need the field "Project" filter projects in accordance with the selected Company.

I tried using $ (). SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns, but as my fields are of type External Data, did not work.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your external data columns can be associated with an External List and may be already. You can filter an external list by mostly the same means you can filter any other list. Here's an example of [how to filter a list with a filter web part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-HA010250989.aspx) that also would apply for an external list.